# Turn off Bluetooth on wakeup from sleep and boot automatically

Tags: 12.04, power-management, bluetooth, suspend

so I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Samsung Series 7 Chronos Laptop. It has i7 cores and Nvidia Optimus Graphics and, needless to say being Samsung, a number of bugs to go along with it.
Basically every time I close the lid for two minutes and open it back up and wake it from suspend, Bluetooth has been re-enabled and I have to disable it again to save on battery.

**Is there a terminal script I can run or a file I can edit to boot with it disabled and keep it disabled on wakeup and login?**

Thanks in advance,
Jack

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal window and type

```
sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

Then Open Dash And Search For "Startup Applications".
Find Bluetooth In The List And Uncheck It. Click Close On The Side.
Hope This Helps!